# Proving diag(A) is SPD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can someone help me with determining if the following statement is true:
If A is symmetric positive definite then diag(A) is symmetric positive definite.

What I have done is:

$u^{T}(diag(A))u=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}u_{i}u_{j}=\sum _{i=1}^{n} a_{ii}u_{i}^2 + \sum_{i \neq j}^{n} a_{ij}u_{i}u_{j}$. 
The last term is equal to 0 because we have a diagonal matrix. The first term is bigger or equal 0 because $a_{ii}>0$ and $u_{i}^2 \geq 0$
So diag(A) is positive semidefinite.

Comment: You are missing a justification as to why $a_{ii} \geq 0$ (not $a_{ii}$ > 0).

Comment: Because we know that A is symmetric positive definite, so by definiton $u^{T}Au>0$.

Comment: But why does this imply that $a_{ii} > 0$? You need to choose an appropriate $u$ and use $u^T A u > 0$ to conclude that $a_{ii} > 0$.

Comment: Ah yes, I already did. But is the conclusion right? Diag(A) is positive semidefinite, so not positive definite?

Comment: If $A$ is positive definite, then $\mathrm{diag}(A)$ will be positive definite. If $A$ is positive semidefinite, then $\mathrm{diag}(A)$ will be positive semidefinite.

Comment: But $u_{i}^2 \geq 0$?

Comment: The definition of a positive definite matrix requires that $u^T A u > 0$ for all $u \neq 0$, not for all $u$. In your case, it will hold.

Answer (score 0):

$a_{ii} = e_i^TAe_i >0$ since $A$ is positive definite. Hence $\operatorname{diag}(A)$ is a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries. This is clearly positive definite.